# http.sslVerify=false doesn't disable ssl verification in git config

Tags: git, ssl, proxy, certificate, config

## Issue:

I have been trying to clone a git repository from a Ubuntu AWS instance, through an http proxy (set in git global config) from an enterprise GitHub server.

Cloning from the proxy works, but cloning from the instance (through the proxy) I get the following error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://githubserver.company.com/repository.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

I have already tried to download the server certificate, add it to my trusted certificates and specify the **http.sslCAInfo** or **http.sslCAPath** options in the git config as specified in many, many other threads.

**Apparently, everyone else who had this issue was able to at least debug the issue or make a one-time exception to security rules by temporarily disabling ssl verification in the git configuration.
Yet using `git config --global http.sslVerify false` or any variation (as a command flag, environment variable, at a local, global or system level, etc.) has no effect.**

This has happened to people with unsynchronized dates/times (but the time in the AWS instance and the proxy are both synchronized through the same ntp server), or in a specific context on Windows, but I cannot find any other instance of this git configuration being ignored like this on a Linux machine.

I am aware that this would have major security implications but not being able to find people with a similar problem makes me think that I must have missed something.

I have gone through dozens and dozens of similar threads and I wasn't able to find a single person with my same issue.

## What I tried:

I got the certificate through:

`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect $hostname:$port -servername $hostname`

placed it in

`/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` as a .pem file

added the certificate to **/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt** through

`sudo update-ca-certificates`.

and added the following options in the git global config:

```
sslCAInfo = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificats.crt
sslCAPath = /etc/ssl/certs/
```

Before trying:

`git config --global http.sslVerify false`

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure: Did you perhaps have the **GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY** set in your user's environment that would override the corresponding global setting http.sslVerify?

Also, I'm not sure whether you should see a tailing slash '/' in reference 'https://githubserver.company.com/repository.git/'. Are you fetching the directory or the repo itself?

Most likely explanation is a broken certificate chain or missing trust.

Perhaps de HTTP proxy server somehow misbehaves are does not allow you to setup the secure connection. Does is support SSL/TLS and does your request run through the appropriate network ports? I'm curious whether you are able to do a (non-git) HTTPS downloads over proxy's from that same target server...