# git clone always fails with "Failed sending HTTP request"

Tags: git, github, ssl-certificate

On one particular host, I cannot git clone any GitHub repo over https:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git
Cloning into 'llvm-project'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git/': Failed sending HTTP request
```

Everything similar I've found talks about SSL server cert verification failing (e.,g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644947/git-http-request-failed) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63490725/http-sslverify-false-doesnt-disable-ssl-verification-in-git-config)). Running the command under `strace` does indicate the command rifling through all my certs before failing, but the `http.sslVerify => false` hack has no effect (just like the second question above).

I've reinstalled the `git` & `ca-certificates` packages; no effect.

Anyone have any thoughts? Even suggestions as to how to induce `git` to tell me more about what's going wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you `git version` is recent enough, you can use [trace2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094711/6309) to display what Git is trying to do:

```
GIT_TRACE2=1 git clone https://...
GIT_TRACE2_EVENT=1 git clone https://...
```

I suspect a different (older) `libcurl` on your host, compared to other ones, which would result in HTTP request being not sent.

You can also, in /usr/bin, check the dynamic library dependencies of git:

```
ldd git
```

Comment: Yup-- that did it. The culprit was not `libcurl`, but some combination of `libgnutls`, `libnettle`, and/or `libhogweed`-- somewhere along the line I built them from source & installed them into `/usr/local/lib`-- git on the bad host was picking them up from there. Moved them away, ran `ldconfig` and `git` worked again. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem with another solution. I post this answer since this problem smh appeared on all my MX Linux boxes at the same time. In my case it was a mismatched version that could be resolved with the solution from [here](https://blog.eastonman.com/blog/2021/04/git-failed-sending-http2-data/).

`# apt reinstall libcurl3-gnutls/stable` did the trick.

It's recommended to have the debian/security apt repos active for this.

Edit: See the answer from gpweb cgti for a more in-depth and permanent solution

Answer (score 5):

Same problem here on Debian Buster!

The problem is reported here:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=987187

My computer was like that:

```sh
DEBIAN10$ apt policy curl:amd64 libcurl4:amd64 libcurl3-gnutls:amd64
curl:
  Instalado: 7.74.0-1.2~bpo10+1
  Candidato: 7.74.0-1.2~bpo10+1
  Tabela de versão:
 *** 7.74.0-1.2~bpo10+1 100
        100 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.64.0-4+deb10u2 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
libcurl4:
  Instalado: 7.74.0-1.2~bpo10+1
  Candidato: 7.74.0-1.2~bpo10+1
  Tabela de versão:
 *** 7.74.0-1.2~bpo10+1 100
        100 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.64.0-4+deb10u2 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
libcurl3-gnutls:
  Instalado: 7.64.0-4+deb10u2
  Candidato: 7.64.0-4+deb10u2
  Tabela de versão:
     7.74.0-1.2~bpo10+1 100
        100 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.64.0-4+deb10u2 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Then, I did the trick!

```sh
DEBIAN10$ apt reinstall libcurl3-gnutls/stable
```

And it is ok now! (thanks @Cobalt)

My config after the change:

```sh
DEBIAN10$ apt policy curl:amd64 libcurl4:amd64 libcurl3-gnutls:amd64
curl:
  Instalado: 7.74.0-1.2~bpo10+1
  Candidato: 7.74.0-1.2~bpo10+1
  Tabela de versão:
 *** 7.74.0-1.2~bpo10+1 100
        100 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.64.0-4+deb10u2 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
libcurl4:
  Instalado: 7.74.0-1.2~bpo10+1
  Candidato: 7.74.0-1.2~bpo10+1
  Tabela de versão:
 *** 7.74.0-1.2~bpo10+1 100
        100 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.64.0-4+deb10u2 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
libcurl3-gnutls:
  Instalado: 7.64.0-4+deb10u2
  Candidato: 7.64.0-4+deb10u2
  Tabela de versão:
     7.74.0-1.2~bpo10+1 100
        100 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.64.0-4+deb10u2 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Besides, add the content bellow to the `/etc/apt/preferences.d/99debian-backports` file, in order to avoid returning to the problem in the next upgrade!

```
/etc/apt/preferences.d/99debian-backports
Package: *
Pin: release a=buster-backports
Pin-Priority: 900

Package: libcurl3-gnutls:amd64
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 901
```

Comment: ```apt-get -t buster reinstall libcurl3-gnutls:amd64=7.64.0-4+deb10u2

Answer (score 2):

For some unknown reason the solution before is not working anymore.
Now, it seams to be fine.

```
sudo apt-get -t buster reinstall libcurl3-gnutls:amd64=7.64.0-4+deb10u2
sudo apt-mark hold libcurl3-gnutls
```